# Can't mount dax format

Tags: yocto

trying to mount dax but got error:

```
root@localhost:~# mount -o dax /dev/pmem0 /mnt
[ 3342.554326] XFS: unknown mount option [dax].
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/pmem0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

should I enable some kernel config to do this?

Comment: your kernel doesn't support it?

Comment: no, I think I need to manually enable some kernel config.

Comment: then... enable it?

Comment: I don't know which one to enable.

Comment: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DAX.html

Comment: no, this is already enabled.